# ASP.NET Web API 2 compatibility

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, iis-8, windows-server-2012, asp.net-4.5

I´m working with web servicesrest, I now that exist web api 2 but the question is,

Is it possible to install WEB API II on a Windows Server 2012 64BITs, with framework 4.5, ISS v.8?

Comment: Your question is not specific enough for an answer.  Please visit the help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is Web API 2.0 supported on .NET 4.5 and IIS8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ASP.NET Web API 2 is supported on IIS 8.